# Animation speed depends on FPS

Tags: java, animation, lwjgl

Im making a simple game and im wanting to link the animation/movement of characters to the time between frames so that in one second the character moves the same distance no matter what the FPS. this is the code I have to try to do this.

```
public void getVels()
{
    if (isAirbourne && accely < terminalVel)
    {
        accely += gravity;
    }

    vely = accely;
    vely = vely * getFrameTime();

    System.out.println(getFrameRate() + "  " + getFrameTime() + "  " + vely);
}
```

.

```
public static long getTime()
{
    return Sys.getTime() * 1000 / Sys.getTimerResolution();
}

public static float getTimeSinceLast()
{
    if (first)
    {
        currentFrame = getTime();
        first = false;
        timeSinceLast = 1;
    }

    else
    {
        lastFrame = currentFrame;
        currentFrame = getTime();
        timeSinceLast = currentFrame - lastFrame;
    }

    return timeSinceLast;
}

public static float getFrameTime()
{
    return timeSinceLast * multiplier;
}

public static void updateClock()
{
    getTimeSinceLast();
}
```

however the game still runs 10x as fast at 100FPS compared to 10FPS even though it shouldn't. Any help/tips?

at 1000 fps getframetime would be 0.01, 
if accely = 1 then vely * getframetime would be 0.01.

at 100fps getframetime is 0.1, so with accely at 1, vely * getframetime should be 0.1

which is 10x larger than 0.01 at a 10x smaller fps so the distance it travels per second should be the same right?

SOLUTION:

```
if (isAirbourne && accely < terminalVel)
{
    accely += gravity * getFrameTime;
}
```

instead of

```
if (isAirbourne && accely < terminalVel)
{
    accely += gravity;
}
```

acceleration from gravity was not adjusted.

Comment: How about using `TimerTask` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html

Comment: Can you please rework this to a [mcve]? It's okay if all it does is print to the console, but this code should be very easy to reduce to a working single running-class example.